# Updating a team's REAL ability

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I am trying to think of a math appropriate way to describe the “real” talent of a team.
This stems from looking at the probabilities of each team winning the Super Bowl.

Let me illustrate with a simple example.  Assume there are only 4 teams in the playoffs, and to keep things simple, three of them (Steelers, Browns, Rams) are of equal ability, and 1 is of lesser ability (the Seahawks)   and the Hawks are given a 30% chance of beating any of these teams.  For the sake of discussion, the Seahawks play the Steelers and the Browns play the Rams.

If you go by the above numbers, the Seahawks, having to win two games, have a 0.3 times 0.3 =.09 chance of winning it all.

I contend that their chances are slightly higher than that because every team can be wrongly assessed, and the teams assessed in the lower rung have a better chance of being undervalued, and conversely, the better you are, the better the chance of being overvalued (kind of a law of diminishing returns for either direction).

I am trying to think of how to best to show/prove that mathematically.

I contend that the Seahawks have a better chance of being higher than 30% against the Browns than lower.  But confidence intervals generally stretch the same amount in both directions, right?

But intuitively, assume a team is at the lower end of the normal distribution, say 3 standard deviations to the left of the mean, and they play a game, and you update their ability away from the mean.  Well, you can’t get much worse than 3 sd’s away from the mean, so in updating their real ability, since we are essentially bounded on the left, it seems they would have a better chance of being better than originally  estimated as opposed to worse than estimated.

I guess what I am asking are there confidence intervals that adjust (get squeezed on the extremes), so to speak, depending upon where you are along the normal distribution continuum?

I am thinking Bayes'  theorem could be used, but I do not want to go there if I do not have to.  Use something like a Poisson distribution?

Comment: You lost me at Superbowl, but that is just me. Otherwise if ability means probability of winning, your probabilities must add to 1 and their distributions are necessarily bounded. In that context. no: confidence intervals do not have to be symmetric. That's my two cents' worth, and I won't be adding to it, given personal ignorance and indifference to sports. Hope you get a much better set of responses.

Comment: I guess to be more consise here, assume you have a random variable that is normally distributed, and you randomly select ten values from that distribution, and the mean of those 10 values fall 3 standard deviations to the left of the mean (assume it is one person taking the SAT 10 different times).  if you were to put a confidence interval around HIS mean (which was 3 sds to the left of the population mean) - part 1

Comment: and take 5 more samples of 10 for just HIM), can we say that those 5 means will fall in a normal distribution ABOUT 3 standard deviations from the original mean  (so, in essence do you have another bell curve at minus 3 standard deviations about the mean)?  if we can, then I think that answers the question, because you could then use the probability density function to argue that those 5 means have a better chance of say falling 2 sds from the population mean as opposed to 4 sds from the population mean.  does that make sense?  would you agree with the last part of what i have said?  part 2

Comment: These comments are open to anyone, but when I said that I would not add further I did mean it, and in any case I can't follow your comments. Sorry, no more.

Comment: yes, I guess I meant it for anyone, though it may have come out otherwise.  Thanks for responses.  to anybody else, as I think more about it, I think it comes down to simply, is the error distribution of a normal distribution also normal?  and I believe it is.